# Neo4j - Cypher query translation from ruby

Tags: neo4j

I have a small neo4j with two node type Author and Book. One single relationship authored_book from Author to Book.
I know bow to get an author by name and all the books he authored from Ruby.
But I don't know how to write the same thing in Cypher.
Here is the Ruby code:

```
2.1.5 :183 > a = Author.find_by(name: 'Albert Camus')
 => #<Author name: "Albert Camus">
2.1.5 :184 > a.books.count
 => 24
2.1.5 :185 > a.books.first
 => #<Book title: "LA Peste (Folio Series: No. 42)">
2.1.5 :186 > a.books.last
 => #<Book title: "La Chute">
2.1.5 :187 >
```

Need to know how to write this in Cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Find and author and all of the authored by books. Return the count of the books, the collections of books, the first book in the collections, the tail of books in the collection and the last book in the collection.

```
match (a:Author {name: 'Albert Camus'})-[:AUTHORED_BOOK]->(b:Book)
return count(b) as Num
, collect(b.title) as Books
, head(collect(b.title)) as Head
, tail(collect(b.title)) as Tail
, last(collect(b.title)) as Last
, collect(b.title)[length(collect(b))-1] as Last2
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, I was away for a while. The count of your query returns 0 rows while the one written in Ruby returns 51 rows. Here it is: a = Author.find_by(name: 'Albert Camus')
 => #<Author name: "Albert Camus">
2.1.5 :002 > a.books.count
 => 51

Comment: This one also returns no records: neo4j-sh (?)$ match (a:Author {name: 'Albert Camus'})-[:AUTHORED_BOOK]->(b:Book) return a, b;
+-------+
| a | b |
+-------+
+-------+
0 row
5 ms

Comment: I fixed it, the name of the relationship should be all small letters, here it is corrected: match (a:Author {name: 'Albert Camus'})-[:authored_book]->(b:Book) return count(b);
+----------+
| count(b) |
+----------+
| 51       |
+----------+
1 row
26 ms

Comment: Is ithere some documentation with examples so I can learn myself more, aside of this group of links https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Search-and-Match ?

Comment: yes - case will get you every time. labels, relationship types, and properties are all case sensitive. everything i ever wanted to know about cypher i learned here ... http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html and here... http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/ and of course reading stackoverflow q & a :)

Comment: Thank you, I will use them.